# IEEE templates for Transaction journals

Tags: publications, journals, ieee

I am trying to figure out which template to use for the journals

IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence

and

IEEE Transactions on Multimedia

Both are journals published by IEEE comsoc, but both also are transactions.

On the IEEE template info page I find separate template for both of them:

http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html

Comment: When in doubt: contact the editor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downoload the templates for Communications Society Journals and open the README, you will find the following note

> This package contains the IEEE Communications Society subset of the full
>   IEEEtran package and is intended for use with IEEE Communications Society
>   publications. The included version of the IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf has been
>   specially formatted in IEEE Communications Society (comsoc) journal mode.

and the disclaimer

> NOTE: Take care not to confuse the "comsoc" and "compsoc" class options/modes as they are very different:
>
> comsoc  ==> IEEE Communications Society
>
> compsoc ==> IEEE Computer
>   Society

The [*IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/aboutJournal.jsp?punumber=34#AimsScope) is *not* published by the IEEE Communications Society but by the IEEE Computer Society (compsoc). Thus, I think that for this you should use the *templates for Computer Society Journals*.

The [*IEEE Transactions on Multimedia*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/aboutJournal.jsp?punumber=6046#AimsScope) seems to be published by both societies and by others too. The [IEEE Transactions on Multimedia](http://signalprocessingsociety.org/publications-resources/ieee-transactions-multimedia) home page links at the [*information for authors*](http://signalprocessingsociety.org/publications-resources/information-authors) page which further links to the [*author digital tools*](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html) page, but saying (bold mine):

> The style files are available on the web at the IEEE Author Digital
>   Toolbox (link is external) under "**Template for all Transactions**."
>   (LaTeX and MS Word).